# Does the gravitational Doppler effect affect charge?

Tags: gravity, charge, doppler-effect

I know that the charge of objects large enough to have distinct gravity is for the most part irrelevant, but large bodies do have (at a given instant) a fixed charge, which, granted, might be hard to read given magnetic fields and charged magneto-spheres, but say that a very massive object, high gravity object, a white dwarf or neutron star, has a defined charge.   Is that charge weakened by the gravitational Doppler effect?

I assume it is weakened because I don't see why it wouldn't be, but I tried looking up the answer using google without success.   If the answer is yes, is there a name for this.  At my level of education, a layman's explanation is a plus.

Comment: How do you define charge in this case? Is it as an integral of the electrical field over a surface surrounding the large body?

Comment: @md2perpe I hadn't thought it in that detail, I was thinking, simple newtonian inverse square law attraction.  Say you have two Neutron stars of equal charge but different mass, hence, different gravitational time dilation and Doppler effect on light - would they have equal attraction to an opposite charge at equal distance (figuring the charge is uniform, which it probably wouldn't be).   I don't understand your comment about integrals over the field and it's been 30 years since I was a student, but I'll do some reading and try to get up to speed.

Comment: Have a look at this image: https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-c615709e9cd943e988b356ce72edf830 The charge $Q$ of the gray ball can be found by integrating the electrical field $\vec E$ over a sphere of some radius $R$ larger than the radius of the ball. Now let the gray ball be for example a black hole and suppose consider the same kind of integral. The question is if it's independent of where inside the sphere a charge is placed. Although being far from an expert on black holes, I'm quite sure it is independent, and that charge is unaffected by gravity.